# Can mousePressed be defined within a class?

Tags: processing

I am trying to create a class called InputManager to handle mouse events. This requires that mousePressed be contained within the InputManager class.

like so

```java
class InputManager{
    void mousePressed(){
       print(hit);
    }
}
```

problem is, that doesn't work. mousePressed() only seems to work when it's outside the class.

How can I get these functions nicely contained in a class?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

in main sketch:

```
InputManager im;

void setup() {
im = new InputManager(this);
registerMethod("mouseEvent", im);

}
```

in InputManager Class:

```
class InputManager {
    void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
         // mousepressed handling code here... 
    }

    void mouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
       switch(e.getAction()) {
          case (MouseEvent.PRESS) : 
               mousePressed();
               break;
          case (MouseEvent.CLICK) :
               mouseClicked();
               break;
          // other mouse events cases here...
       }
    }
}
```

Once you registered InputManger mouseEvent in PApplet you don't need to call it and it will be called each loop at the end of draw().

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly, but you are responsible for ensuring it gets called:

```
interface P5EventClass {
  void mousePressed();
  void mouseMoved();
  // ...
}

class InputManager implements P5EventClass {
  // we MUST implement mousePressed, and any other interface method
  void mousePressed() {
    // do things here
  }
}

// we're going to hand off all events to things in this list
ArrayList<P5EventClass> eventlisteners = new ArrayList<P5EventClass>();

void setup() {
  // bind at least one input manager, but maybe more later on.
  eventlisteners.add(new InputManager());
}

void draw() {
  // ...
}

void mousePressed() {
  // instead of handling input globally, we let
  // the event handling obejct(s) take care of it
  for(P5EventClass p5ec: eventlisteners) {
   p5ec.mousePressed();
  }
}
```

I would personally make it a bit tighter by also passing the event variables explicitly, so "void mousePressed(int x, int y);" in the interface and then calling "p5ec.mousePressed(mouseX, mouseY);" in the sketch body, simply because relying on globals rather than local variables makes your code prone to concurrency bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so would be:

```
class InputManager{
    void mousePressed(){
       print(hit);
    }
}

InputManager im = new InputManager();

void setup() {
   // ...
}

void draw() {
   // ...
}

void mousePressed() {
   im.mousePressed();
}
```

This should solve any problems you were having with variable scoping in your class.

Note: In the class, it doesn't even have to be named mousePressed, you can name it anything you wish, as long as you call it inside of the main mousePressed method.